# executar um script pressionando um botão com atributo data

Tags: jquery

Fiz um form html, o coloquei em uma plataforma que carrega esse form. Porem existem botões da plataforma que executam funções no form (como enviar o form, salvar e etc). Ai descobri que posso manipular esses botões da plataforma com códigos dentro do form utilizando isso:

```
window.parent
```

por exemplo, eu posso soltar um alert quando certo botão da plataforma for pressionado com esse código:

```
window.parent.$(".fixedTopBar").find("button").on("click", function(ev) { alert("OK"); });
```

Ai, eu tenho este botão (que logicamente não posso alterar ele, pois é da plataforma):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-send="">Enviar</button>
```

E quero rodar um script quando ele é pressionado... Como tenho outros botões na página, eu decidi capturar o "on(click)" do botão com o data-send (já que ele é único nisso).

Tentei códigos como:

```
window.parent.$('[data-send]').on("click", function(ev) { alert("OK"); ); 

window.parent.$('button[data-send]').on("click", function(ev) { alert("OK"); );    

window.parent.$('button').data("send").on("click", function(ev) { alert("OK"); });
```

Porem não funcionou. Eu não entendo muito sobre o atributo data... Deve ser dai a dificuldade de entender como utilizar ele.

Caso seja melhor, desenhei como é:
[Vermelho] Ambiente
[Azul] form
[Seta Verde] Botão que eu quero capturar o click

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: Esse botão está presente quando a página carrega? Testa `$(document).on("click", '[data-send]', function(ev) { alert("OK"); ); `

Comment: Na realidade, eu não postei o código todo... É uma janela que fica fora do documento... Eu utilizo um: window.parent. antes.

Comment: Como que o elemento fica fora do documento?

Comment: Isso é dentro de uma plataforma que uma janela carrega um documento externo ai esse botão que eu quero capturar fica na janela, não no documento... Já fiz testes como: window.parent.$("#workflowActions").on("click", function(ev) { va(ev); }); e funciona...

Comment: Resolvido! Adicionado na pergunta e aqui:
`window.parent.$("[data-send='']").on("click", function(ev) { validateForms(ev); });`

Comment: Não poste a sua solução editando a pergunta; para isso existe a área de respostas. Não há problemas em responder a própria pergunta; de fato, isso é bastante comum aqui, mas busque estruturá-la bem, não apenas com uma linha de código, mas com uma explicação do porquê não funcionava da maneira que estava e porquê seu código solucionou o problema. Se você não entende completamente o porquê da solução funcionar e as outras apresentadas na pergunta não, seu problema ainda não foi resolvido.

Comment: Até porque seu exemplo de `$('button[data-send]')` deveria funcionar. Veja [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/ko5rgLkL/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido. Primeiro tive que fazer uma alteração:
em vez de usar o select button, eu usei o atributo data-send, pois existe outro elemento no ambiente que envia (e também tem o mesmo atributo data-send) porem não é botão. Ou seja, desse código:

```
$('button[data-send]')
```

eu fui pra esse código:

```
$("[data-send]")
```

Assim, o script engloba os dois casos.

Sobre esse código da pergunta não funcionar:

```
window.parent.$('[data-send]').on("click", function(ev) { alert("OK"); );
```

Ele funciona normalmente, deve ter acontecido algum problema (ou da plataforma, ou cache ou até mesmo alguma aspas ou ponto faltando) e quando eu executei achei que não funcionava.